# Proc report with numeric variables

Tags: sas

I recently came across an issue when using `Proc report` whereby the below code outputs only the first observation:

```
data have ;
  input var1-var3 ;
datalines ;
1 10 100
2 20 200
3 30 300
4 40 400 
;run ;

proc report data=have ;
columns var1 var2 var3 ;
  define var1 / 'Variable 1' width=10;
  define var2 / 'Variable 2' width=10;
  define var3 / 'Variable 3' width=10;
run ;
```

It will report all 4 observations correctly by either:

1. Changing `var1` to be a character variable (`input var1 $ var2-var3`)
2. Explicitly defining `define var1` to be `define var1 / display`

I'm trying to work out the logic of why this would be happening. It can't be that having the first variable in the report as numeric defaults to a `group` variable rather than `display` as all `var1` values are unique so should be grouped separately - whereas only the first observation is reported. Can someone explain the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the answer of what's happening behind the scenes by adding the `list` option to the proc report statement...

**`input var1-var3`** (3x numeric) puts the following to the log:

```
PROC REPORT DATA=WORK.HAVE LS=120 PS=44  SPLIT="/" CENTER ;
COLUMN  ( var1 var2 var3 );

DEFINE  var1 / SUM FORMAT= BEST9. WIDTH=10    SPACING=2   RIGHT "Variable 1" ;
DEFINE  var2 / SUM FORMAT= BEST9. WIDTH=10    SPACING=2   RIGHT "Variable 2" ;
DEFINE  var3 / SUM FORMAT= BEST9. WIDTH=10    SPACING=2   RIGHT "Variable 3" ;
RUN;
```

**`input var1 $ (var2 var3) (:)`** (setting first to character) puts the following to the log:

```
PROC REPORT DATA=WORK.HAVE LS=120 PS=44  SPLIT="/" CENTER ;
COLUMN  ( var1 var2 var3 );

DEFINE  var1 / DISPLAY FORMAT= $8. WIDTH=10    SPACING=2   LEFT "Variable 1" ;
DEFINE  var2 / SUM FORMAT= BEST9. WIDTH=10    SPACING=2   RIGHT "Variable 2" ;
DEFINE  var3 / SUM FORMAT= BEST9. WIDTH=10    SPACING=2   RIGHT "Variable 3" ;
RUN;
```

So, knowing that numeric variables have a default value of `SUM` at least explains what was causing it. Although it causes a problem on simple report like this, it does at least report a sum correctly if `var1` is defined as a `by` group:

```
data have ;
  input var1 var2 var3 ;
datalines ;
1 10 100
1 15 150
2 20 200
3 30 300
4 40 400 
;run ;

proc report data=have list ;
columns var2 var3 ;
by var1 ;
  define var2 / 'Variable 2' width=10;
  define var3 / 'Variable 3' width=10;
run ;
```

Comment: When I run the code in your question it reports the sums correctly (`10  100  1000`). What is not correct about it?

Comment: Hi @DWal, it's not that it was wrong - just that I thought the default assignment in `define` was always `DISPLAY` and not `SUM`

Answer (score 0):

You should just add options which describes what kind of variables they are; like `group` or `analysis`, like below:

```
proc report nowd data=have ;
  columns var1 var2 var3 ;
  define var1 / group width=10 'Variable 1';
  define var2 / analysis width=10 'Variable 2';
  define var3 / analysis width=10 'Variable 3'; 
run ;
```

Here is the result:

```
  Variable 1  Variable 2  Variable 3
           1          10         100
           2          20         200
           3          30         300
           4          40         400
```

Comment: Thanks - although I was trying to find out what the default assignment when it wasn't specified